# How to get UIElement as custom UserControl from ItemsControl ItemsSource by ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have an `ItemsControl` that has an `ObservableCollection<ViewModels>` as an `ItemsSource`, these ViewModels have a UserControl as a `DataContext`. So here's the question: how do I get the generated collection of UI UserControls from `ItemsControl`?

I have a next code:
This is `ItemsControl` (With Binding to `ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>`)

```xml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged"
                x:Name="scroll">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Interlocutor.Messages}"
                        x:Name="itemsControl"
                        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MessageViewModel}">
                    <controls:MessageControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is my UserControl (`MessageControl`) and `DataContext` binding:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Client.Controls.MessageControl"
             ...
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Client.ViewModels"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:MessageViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
```

And I tried this:

```cs
foreach (MessageViewModel item in itemsControl.Items)
{
    MessageControl control = (MessageControl)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

And this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
{
    MessageControl element = (MessageControl)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
}
```

But to no avail. This returns a `ContentPresenter` object containing the `Content` property with my ViewModel.

Comment: Are you reading or writing data to the database (data context)?  If you are reading from database and putting results in to the View you can get the data instead from the DataContext.

Comment: @jdweng, no. i need mark this messages as read if the user sees them and notify about it to server

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant parts of your code as text, not as links to images.

Comment: It is wrong to assume that the MessageControl from the ItemTemplate is the item container. To achieve that, you would have to create a derived ItemsControl class that overrides the GetContainerForItemOverride method.

Comment: Why do you need to reference those usercontrols?   It's more usual to work with properties in viewmodels and make things happen in the view using binding.

Comment: @Andy, I need to subscribe to the event of a user interface element to find out when it became visible to the user directly when scrolling ScrollViewer, and mark as read only those messages that are visible.

Comment: I would think the loaded event of the usercontrol will fire as it becomes visible. Why can't you set a property in the viewmodel from there? You could add an attached property yo your usercontrol and bind to a property in the viewmodel.

Comment: @Andy, the ViewModel knows nothing about the UserControl, as MVVM assumes. But at the same time only UserControl has bounds for check it visibile

Comment: Read the part about binding again.

Comment: @Andy, UIControl no has Property of real visibility in ScrollViewer scrolling. UIElement has bounds with which I can Calculate visibile Rectangles on ChatView.

Comment: What do you think virtualization does?

Comment: @Andy, I thought virtualization cleans memory of invisible elements, but I do not know how it happens under the hood. Does virtualization just set the Visibility = false property? If this is the case, then I think it will make the task much easier.

Comment: Read about the various modes for virtualisation.  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ListBoxItemLoaded"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Unloaded" Handler="ListBoxItemUnloaded"/>
        </Style>

Comment: *"I need to subscribe to the event of a user interface element to find out when it became visible to the user directly when scrolling ScrollViewer, and mark as read only those messages that are visible."* - When everything the user can see is read-only, then simply make all items read-only by default.

Comment: The `VirtualiozingStackPanel` has no function in your code. It is used like a common `StackPanel`. To enable virtualization you must override the `ItemsControl.Template` and wrap the `ItemsPresenter` into a `ScrollViewer` and set `ScrollViewer.CanItemsScroll` to `true`. Don't wrap the `ItemsControl` into a `ScrollViewer` (you don't want to scroll the `ItemsControl` but the items of the `ItemsControl`). Afgter overrideing the template as explained the `VirtualizingStackPanel` can finally virtualize the  items.

Comment: If you want UI virtualization and a scrollable `ItemsControl` you must use the `ListBox` instead. It has virtualization enabled by default and also features a `ScrollViewer`. No need to implement it yourself.

Comment: In case you want to mark the `MessageViewModel` as read-only you should bind it to the `MessageControl`. Let the `MessageControl` track its visibility and toggle a corresponding property accordingly. Then bind this property to the `MessageViewModel` to change its state.